# Android - do I need to run zipAlign after I run jarSigner?

Tags: android, apk

I just successfully signed an android app I am trying to RE-publish to the store. I can't recall if I have to run zipAlign after jarSigner? Or after I run jarSigner I am all good?

I am looking here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html and not really finding the answer to that in the "Publishing Updates on Google Play" section.

Also, when I upload the new apk, do I have to deactivate the old one? Or just upload over the old one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/zipalign.html

> Caution: You must use zipalign at one of two specific points in the app-building process, depending on which app-signing tool you use:
>
> If you use apksigner, zipalign must only be performed before the APK file has been signed. If you sign your APK using apksigner and make further changes to the APK, its signature is invalidated.
>
> If you use jarsigner, zipalign must only be performed after the APK file has been signed.